# How do I play Parkour Fortress?

Tags: team-fortress-2

So far I've played a little bit of Parkour Fortress, but I've seen others using moves that I can't seem to know how to use.

I know the basics, wallrunning, sliding, and rolling after a long jump, but I've seen some moves that boost the character forward, and other moves allowing for faster speeds.

ARe there any special moves not in the tutorial?  How do I play Parkour Fortress? What moves are available to me?

Here's the IP of the Parkour Fortress server:

> 66.150.121.42:27015

Comment: I don't know what Parkour Fortress is, but I now know what has been missing from my life

Comment: Server ip is here: 66.150.121.42:27015 to start off just type /tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Running

The most basic move.   Run without losing momentum (ie, dont press backwards or strafe), and you will get to running speed when you have a speed boost effect similar to a Disciplinary Whip. The longer you can run without bumping into objects in front of you or losing momentum, the faster your speed builds up (slowly, but surely).

---

### Jumping

You get two jumps, just like the normal Scout class.  A word of caution.  There is a hidden gravity setting, so if you try to extend air time by jumping too late, you will drop down extremely fast, most likely stunning or killing you.

---

### Falling

Under certain conditions, falling will either have no effect on you or end up killing you

- Short fall distance: no effect
- Medium fall distance: lose all momentum. Will lose a little HP.
- Long fall distance: Stun for x seconds (based on fall distance). Will lose some HP.
- Very long fall damage: You die.

Don't worry about falling.  As long as you don't do it too often, your health will slowly regenerate.

---

### Wall-Running

Run forwards and press and hold the direction of the wall you're wallrunning on and press jump.  You should do this action right before you actually reach the wall you want to run on.  New players make the mistake of trying to do it after reaching the wall.

---

### Wall-Climbing

If you are trying to reach a ledge that's way too far above you, simply look up towards the top of the wall, hold forward, and press jump to start "wall climbing".  After a short time, you will lose momentum and drop back to the group, so jump before this happens to achieve a higher jump.

---

### Ledge Grab

If you are close to an edge on any prop/building, you can stay still while hanging on the side of the prop.  Press jump to go above edge, or press crouch to drop down.

---

### Zip-line

Click on the zip-line when you reach it.  You can hit crouch mid zip-line to drop down earlier.

---

### Sliding

On downwards slopes, hold down Crouch to achieve a slightly faster speed boost (faster than running).  The animation should change to reflect a sliding stance.

---

### Rolling

If you are falling, and you fall from a relatively high distance (but not enough to kill you), you can hit Crouch right before hitting the ground to perform a roll.   This will allow you to preserve momentum and not be stunned (see Falling).

---

### Leap/SuperJump

When in the Running mode (when you see speed lines effect), and on the ground, right click to launch yourself in the direction you are viewing.   When landing, you will lose ALL momentum.

---

**Last Notes:**

Calling for Medic! (default 'E', or 'Z,1') will enable you to quickly reset your progress to the starting line.